# PHP - Native function to get all the values of an array by their index

Tags: php, arrays

I need to know if there is a native PHP function that allows me to get all the values of an array, specifying the indices to get, WITHOUT CYCLING, for example

**I have this Array listing in a function:**

```
function get_mime($index)
{
    $data = array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'zip' => 'application/x-compressed',
        'doc' => 'application/msword',
        'dot' => 'application/msword',
        'docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'dotx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
        'docm' => 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12',
        'dotm' => 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12',
        'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xlt' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xla' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'xltx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template',
        'xlsm' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12',
        'xltm' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12',
        'xlam' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12',
        'xlsb' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12',
        'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'pot' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'pps' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'ppa' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'pptx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        'potx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template',
        'ppsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow',
        'ppam' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12',
        'pptm' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12',
        'potm' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12',
        'ppsm' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12'
    );
    return $data;
}
```

**And I need to call this function:**

```
get_mime(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'));
```

**And to return an array with values:**

```
array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif')
```

Comment: Have you tried to read about functions that I ponted you ?

Comment: 1) Why. 2) Do you believe "native" functions don't perform loops?

Comment: Whether you use a function that does a loop behind the scenes, or write a loop yourself... I fail to see the difference.

Comment: I think that with a native function it is much easier and clean the code and it is what I always look for a very simple, clean and practical code

Comment: 1) You don't know this "native" function you're talking about. 2) Why would it be cleaner? Control structures like loops exist for a reason. Create your function to do one thing and one thing only, use a loop and voila - clean and nice code is here. I see nothing in native function that helps you whatsoever, if it even existed. However, it's your code, so have fun with looking for that mysterious function.

Comment: I had to use three functions to do this, and I wanted to know if there is a single function that would allow me to achieve this, so I see it is easier to use a cycle, but the only thing I want to know is if there is a native PHP function That is able to obtain this result, only with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = array_intersect_key(array_flip(['jpg', 'png', 'gif']), $data);
```

Comment: `array_intersect_key` uses the values of the first array. If you switch arguments, your solution is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_mime($index)
{
    $data = array(
       //...
    );
    return array_values(
        array_intersect_key(
            $data, array_combine(
                $index, array_fill(
                    0, count($index)
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Technically, that's only native functions w/o PHP loop. But of course, under the hood PHP will loop through both arrays several times.

I would not suggest this solution in general. Usually a simple `for` loop is more efficient and more readable.